# Using %r with input() in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm new to python and having a bit of trouble. If you guys could help explain how to do this and why it works the way it does would be awesome. I'm doing the learn python the hard way lesson 11 in python 3 trying to make the change over. I've looked for the last hour or so trying to figure this out. I have tried all kinds of (), " ", ' ' combo's. Thanks for the help. I'm struggling with the step over to python 3 from codecademy python tutorials I've done. Here is what I originally wrote be for i messed with it.

I have tried putting it outside the () and in there own () but I keep reading errors.

```
print ("How old are you?"),
age = input("Enter: ")
print ("How tall are you?"),
height = input("Enter:")
print ("What are you in to?"),
interest = input("Enter: ")

print ("So your %r and %r tall. Cool what do you like?"),
print ("I like  to do %r "),
```

This code is running fine but the %r is not replacing with the user input().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention which variables you want to substitute:

```
print("So your %r and %r tall. Cool what do you like?" % (age, height))
```

The string `%r` is not special in any way: it is just a placeholder value that is recognized by the formatting operator `%`.

Note: the trailing comma does not accomplish anything in Python 3 because `print` is just a regular function.  If you want to suppress the newline, use the following instead:

```
print(..., end="")
```

In general, when reading Python documentation, guides, and tutorials, it's a good idea to check what *version* it targets.  Python 2 and 3 have some significant differences.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me this way. I'm gonna practice this tonight you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
print("So your {} and {} tall. Cool what do you like?".format(age,height))
```

Comment: Yours works really well I'll have to keep this in mind.

Answer (score -2):

try like this

```
print("So your",age, "and", height, "tall. Cool what do you like?")
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it with out using variable names. Thank you for the help though. I appreciate it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Interrobang yep , but its just a another proposal