# (new) python questions about user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-3.3

Okay so i have a question on user input, this is fairly simple and i'm new
so..I'm using python 3.3 and if i were to type

```
input("Enter name and age: ")
```

How do i put together an if statement that records the name and age and tells the user:

```
print("Your name is this and your age is that")
```

with the values that they inserted,
PS, I'm using notepad++ as the IDE
and cmd to enter the input for the code.
So no python shells.
Thanks in advance, please explain in detail how your answers work
because i'm fairly new to python, I've been scripting on actionscript before
but it was too outdated so i know a few things or 2 about loops but i never really scripted input data which can be recorded.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using %r with input() in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750499/using-r-with-input-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name, age = input("Enter name and age: ").split()
print("Your name is {this} and your age is {that}".format(this=name, that=age))
```